# Moor_flutter limit() method not working / it is being ignored

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, limit, flutter-moor

I'm working with sqlite database using [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter) package to do so. I've been trying to apply `limit` method to a certain query but it is not working. Inside the `limit` method I'm parsing `int _limit` parameter value and also the optional `offset: int _offset` parameter value.

I'm not getting no error and I'm not sure why this is not working. See the code below.

```dart
Stream<List<PersonWithProducts>> watchAllPersons(int _limit, int _offset) {
    return (select(persons)
          ..orderBy(
            [
              (t) =>
                  OrderingTerm(expression: t.created, mode: OrderingMode.desc),
              (t) => OrderingTerm(expression: t.name),
            ],
          )..limit(_limit, offset: _offset))
        .join(
          [
            leftOuterJoin(products, products.guest_person_id.equalsExp(persons.id)),
          ],
        )
        .watch()
        .map((rows) => rows.map(
              (row) {
                return PersonWithProuducts(
                  person: row.readTable(persons),
                  product: row.readTable(products),
                );
              },
            ).toList());
  }
```

**Note** There are more than `20` records in the Table. When I call the function above All data from database table is fetched instead of the specified limit, It is like the `limit()` method is being ignored.

See below code, this is where I'm calling the above function

```dart
int limit = 5;
int offset = 0;

return StreamBuilder(
      stream: personDao.watchAllPersons(limit, offset),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PersonWithProducts>> snapshot) {
        final persons = snapshot.data ?? List();
        // print('snapshot data: ${snapshot.data}');
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: persons.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              final personInfo = persons[index];
              return _buildListItem(
                  personInfo, personDao);
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: AwesomeLoader(
              loaderType: AwesomeLoader.AwesomeLoader4,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

What I want is the `watchAllPersons` function to fetch the data according to the specified `limit`. I want to make the `limit` method work. Thank you, so much Love.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you providing underscore to the 'limit' variable it means you are making the variable private.

Answer (score 0):

Although its been some time, I forgot to provide solution, This was a bug in the package I posted issue [here](https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/433).